# PLSQL: remove unwanted double quotes in a Json

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a Json like this (it is contained in a clob variable):

```
{"id": "33", "type": "abc", "val": "2", "cod": "", "sg1": "1", "sg2": "1"}
{"id": "359", "type": "abcef", "val": "52", "cod": "aa", "sg1": "", "sg2": "0"}
…
```

I need to remove `"` from values of: `id`, `val`, `sg1`, `sg2`

Is it possibile?

For example, I need to obtain this:

```
{"id": 33, "type": "abc", "val": 2, "cod": "", "sg1": 1, "sg2": 1}
{"id": 359, "type": "abcef", "val": 52, "cod": "aa", "sg1": , "sg2": 0}
…
```

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: `"sg1": ,` isn't valid. Also wouldn't it be better to fix whatever is creating the JSON, rather than trying to manipulate it afterwards?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it's an external application that produce it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 12 (R2?) or later then you can convert your JSON to the appropriate data types and then convert it back to JSON.

**Oracle 18 Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value CLOB );
INSERT INTO test_data ( value )
  VALUES ( '{"id": "33", "type": "abc", "val": "2", "cod": "", "sg1": "1", "sg2": "1"}' );
INSERT INTO test_data ( value )
  VALUES ( '{"id": "359", "type": "abcef", "val": "52", "cod": "aa", "sg1": "", "sg2": "0"}' );
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         'id'   IS j.id,
         'type' IS j.typ,
         'val'  IS j.val,
         'cod'  IS j.cod,
         'sg1'  IS j.sg1,
         'sg2'  IS j.sg2
       ) AS JSON
FROM   test_data t
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$'
         COLUMNS
           id  NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.id',
           typ VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.type',
           val NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.val',
           cod VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.cod',
           sg1 NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.sg1',
           sg2 NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.sg2'
       ) j
```

**Output**:

```
| JSON                                                             |
| :--------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"id":33,"type":"abc","val":2,"cod":null,"sg1":1,"sg2":1}        |
| {"id":359,"type":"abcef","val":52,"cod":"aa","sg1":null,"sg2":0} |
```

Or, if you want to use regular expressions (you shouldn't if you have the choice and should use a proper JSON parser instead) then:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         REGEXP_REPLACE(
           value,
           '"(id|val|sg1|sg2)": ""',
           '"\1": "null"'
         ),
         '"(id|val|sg1|sg2)": "(\d+|null)"',
         '"\1": \2'
       ) AS JSON
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

```
| JSON                                                                        |
| :-------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"id": 33, "type": "abc", "val": 2, "cod": "", "sg1": 1, "sg2": 1}          |
| {"id": 359, "type": "abcef", "val": 52, "cod": "aa", "sg1": null, "sg2": 0} |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e41866c23bcc0543209771263892bd5)*